# How can I limit the number of password attempts in a simple form?

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm trying to make a basic password checker with 3 attempts using a textbox and button. So in the HTML I have these two elements and a paragraph in which I want to post the answer (correct, wrong, out of entries).

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Test page for Java.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Java Tester</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input id="textbox" type="text">
    <button id="button">Enter</button>
    <p id="answer"></p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am using a while loop for the attempts in JavaScript. I understand that the following code does not work, as entering the wrong answer the first time loops three times and goes straight to "out of entries". I'm trying to figure out how to write this, so I have three attempts.

JavaScript code:

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var password = "wordpass";
var response;
var entryCount = 0;
var entryLimit = 3;
var error = false;

button.addEventListener("click", function(){

  while(textbox.value != password && !error){
    if(entryCount < entryLimit){
      answer.innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
      entryCount++;
      textbox.value = "";
    } else{
      error = true;
    }
  }

  if(error){
    answer.innerHTML = "Out of entries";
  } else{
    answer.innerHTML = "Correct Password";
  }
```

**However**, I figured if I just write some random text in the while loop just under `textbox.value="";` it starts working the way I want it to - I can input the pass 3 times. Why is this? Just for clearance here is the JS code that works.

Working JS code:

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var password = "wordpass";
var response;
var entryCount = 0;
var entryLimit = 3;
var error = false;

button.addEventListener("click", function(){

  while(textbox.value != password && !error){
    if(entryCount < entryLimit){
      answer.innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
      entryCount++;
      textbox.value = "";
      ousdgohjrandomfoihsodfhsdfhsdofihoihsoidhsdoufhouhsdfrduiiugsdf
    } else{
      error = true;
    }
  }

  if(error){
    answer.innerHTML = "Out of entries";
  } else{
    answer.innerHTML = "Correct Password";
  }

});
```

Comment: It works without that randome text. And why you need a while loop can you please explain.https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/wra9t30L/2/

Comment: The reason the second code works is that it forces an error to happen, preventing the while loop from running more than once. As stated in the answer, you don't need a while loop for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code reacting to the click event doesn't "pause" and wait for UI input again, so the while loop isn't really necessary. You could replace it with an if-check, and then reset the retry count on success. You can also drop the `error` variable and move the answer responses in its place.

I've also changed the logic a bit to check the retry count as the first check; otherwise the user would be able to continue to guess even if they exceed the retry count.

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");  
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var password = "wordpass";
var entryCount = 0;
var entryLimit = 3;

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (entryCount < entryLimit) {
    if (textbox.value != password){
      answer.innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
      entryCount++;
      textbox.value = "";
    } else {
      // success!
      entryCount = 0;
      answer.innerHTML = "Correct Password";
    }
  } else {
      answer.innerHTML = "Out of entries";
  }
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");  
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var password = "wordpass";
var entryCount = 0;
var entryLimit = 3;

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (entryCount < entryLimit) {
    if (textbox.value != password){
      answer.innerHTML = "Wrong Password";
      entryCount++;
      textbox.value = "";
    } else {
      // success!
      entryCount = 0;
      answer.innerHTML = "Correct Password";
    }
  } else {
      answer.innerHTML = "Out of entries";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" placeholder="Password" />
<button id="button" type="button">Login</button>

<div id="answer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not working the first time because the while loop is unnecessary. It is looping over the same answer until errorcount is exceeded. When you add the random text, it throws an runtime error and breaks the loop in the first run. Replacing the while with a simple if should work.